# Mongodb error: JavaScript execution failed

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In my application i am executing following query on Mongodb collection. It moves all the records of `collection` to `his_collection`

```
`for record in collection.find():
    his_collection.insert(record)

 collection.remove()`
```

With **3k** rows in `collection` table it works fine i.e All the rows are moved to his_collection.

But when i executed the above command With **10k** rows in `collection`. It hanged

Now when i am trying to connect Mongodb with command `mongo` in shell it throws following **Error**

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
Fri Aug 23 12:41:28.762 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to
server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
```

I tried following commands in shell to get rid of this problem

```
service mongodb stop
rm /mnt-data/data/mongodb/mongod.lock
mongod –repair --dbpath=/mnt-data/data/mongodb/
service mongodb start
```

Please suggest me any suggestion what should i do?

**LOG for mongod -repair**

```
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.617 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16997 port=27017
dbpath=/mnt-data/data/mongodb/ 64-bit host=
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.618 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.5
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.618 [initandlisten] git version: 
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.618 [initandlisten] build info: Linux 
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.618 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.618 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/mnt-data/data/mongo
db/", repair: true }
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.625 [initandlisten] ****
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.625 [initandlisten] ****
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.625 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database jf_db with pdfi
le version 4.5, new version: 4.5
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.625 [initandlisten]          starting upgrade
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.625 [initandlisten]  jf_db repairDatabase jf_db
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.626 [initandlisten]  jf_db Cannot repair database jf_db havi
ng size: 12829327360 (bytes) because free disk space is: 3514216448 (bytes)
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.626 [initandlisten]  jf_db Assertion failure doDBUpgrade( db
Name , errmsg , h ) src/mongo/db/db.cpp 353
0xdd9e31 0xd9b04d 0x6d3116 0x6d6e88 0x6d74cd 0x6ddfb0 0x6dfc09 0x7f8ee2ba976d 0x
6cf979
mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdd9e31]
mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0xfd) [0xd9b04d]
mongod() [0x6d3116]
mongod(_ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi+0x5d8) [0x6d6e88]
mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x1d) [0x6d74cd]
mongod() [0x6ddfb0]
mongod(main+0x9) [0x6dfc09]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f8ee2ba976d]
mongod(__gxx_personality_v0+0x499) [0x6cf979]
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.629 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 0 assertion
src/mongo/db/db.cpp:353, terminating
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.629 dbexit:
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.629 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening socke
ts...
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.629 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.629 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.629 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.629 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.631 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.631 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Fri Aug 23 12:56:36.631 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: What do the mongod logs say?

Comment: Wait I am updating the log in my question

Comment: Seems like you need to free up some disk space to be able to run the repair

Answer (score -1):

You need to add considerably more disk space. I've seen repairs run from 2x datasize to 50x datasize - depending on how badly the data is corrupted.